# SAML - Unable to get back to SP site after logout from Azure AD(IDP)

Tags: single-sign-on, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0

We are using standard SAML request-response to authenticate users in our application.

We have integrated three identity providers

1. OKTA
2. OneLogin
3. Azure AD

For all of three above, SSO is working fine. for SLO(Single Logout), OKTA and Onelogin are fine. but on azure ad, when it request for SLO to azure ad app, it successfully logs-out the user and display a message on their page. but after logout it doesn't redirect-back to our application. This functionality is working fine for other two.

Interesting thing is Azure ad never asked me to enter ReturnURL for logout when i created/setup application on it. In short, we are providing any details that where to redirect after logout to azure ad.

Where and How we can provide returnURL for logout on azure ad?

Can we have an option to send returnURL with request in case of azure ad?

Thanks,

Mitesh J.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, it will try to redirect you to ConsumerUrl and there you need to check Is it an authorized request ?? or not and move forward ...
In our case, we are using  an Identity server as middleware  that handles those things, We just need to to give some Configuration

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD portal has the option to specify the logout url. According to the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-single-sign-on-non-gallery-applications#step-1-edit-the-basic-saml-configuration

Logout URL : Used to send the SAML Logout responses back to the application.

You can also see the option in attached screenshot[image]